# Responsive framework misbehaving

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, viewport

I've developed a site using Bootstrap as my framework.  My responsive layout is misbehaving on some tablets and phones.

1. When testing on my Android Galaxy Tab and Kindle the site only fills half the screen.
2. The site loads properly on the iPhone in portrait but when rotated to landscape it seems to zoom in and only shows half of the page. The opposite of the Android issue.

I have my meta viewport set as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Has anybody else ever experienced these issues? I can't seem to figure out what would be causing this. When I test on my desktop in Chrome and Firefox the layout collapses and expands as expected.

I do have one oversized div within a container. Here is my stripped down code:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="slider-container">
          <div class="slider">

          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.container {
max-width: 1000px;
}

.slider-container {
width: 100%;
}

.slider {
width: 2400px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it fills half size or more or less, you have to check for overflows that elements can causing.

Check for specially;

- Sliders
- Menus

If you have any online sample, i can help you more.

Comment: I do have one div that I have set to a fairly large width but it's within a containing div with overflow set to hidden. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Maybe. Check it's parent element and if not check your other elements.

Comment: I added my stripped down html and css above, could the slider div be causing this issue?

Comment: your slider class has 2400px width. That's the problem. Give your .slider-container > overflow:hidden and remove that from .slider.